# Problem with changed content of elements - how could I get the new values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to generate a simple form which shows data from a database and lets the user update this data.

I receive the data via a servlet and pass it to front end in form of a JSON file. I generate a table and display the values. The first two values are integers, the last two are texts, so I chose `<input type='number \>` for the first and `<textarea><\textarea>` for the last.

**The Problem:** When I change the content by entering a new text or number, and hit the button, the generated JSON still shows the old values. How could I get the new ones?

```js
var $tbl = $("#table1");
var index = 1
var item = ["id", "1", "2", "text1", "text2"]
$(
    "<tr><th>Number</th><th>Number 2</th><th>Text</th><th>Text 2</th></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl)
$("<tr><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_from' value='" +
    item[1] +
    "'/></td><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_to' value='" +
    item[2] +
    "' /></td><td><textarea rows='1' cols='40' id='" +
    index +
    "_sub'>" +
    item[3] +
    "</textarea></td><td><textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='" +
    index +
    "_txt'>" +
    item[4] +
    "</textarea></td></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl);

$("body").append("<input type='button' id='btn_1' value='button'>");
$("#btn_1").click(htmltable2json)

function htmltable2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var myRows = [];
  var headersText = [];
  var $headers = $("#table1 th");

  var $rows = $("#table1 tr").each(function(index) {
    $cells = $(this).find("td");
    myRows[index - 1] = {};

    $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
      // Set the header text
      if (headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
        headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
      }
      myRows[index - 1][headersText[cellIndex]] = $($(this).html()).val() ? $($(this).html()).val() : $(this).text();
    });
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(myRows));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1"></table>
```

Comment: `I receive the data via a servlet and pass it to front end in form of a JSON file.` <-- So, the new data will need to go back to the server so it can be used to generate a new JSON file.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, the content of the alert in my example will be send back to the server, along with other data.

Comment: Did you test what data is going to the server when you click and then what happens to that data on its way back?

Comment: I replaced the original JSON with the item-array because this part is more an introduction part of my post - my problem is about getting the new values after a change in the front end input/textarray-fields, as `$(this).text()` shows the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you get the value from the cell input.

You should use something like `$(this).children().first().val()`

I suggest you to add a class on your inputs, so it would be easier to select them.

```js
var $tbl = $("#table1");
var index = 1
var item = ["id", "1", "2", "text1", "text2"]
$(
    "<tr><th>Number</th><th>Number 2</th><th>Text</th><th>Text 2</th></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl)
$("<tr><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_from' value='" +
    item[1] +
    "'/></td><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_to' value='" +
    item[2] +
    "' /></td><td><textarea rows='1' cols='40' id='" +
    index +
    "_sub'>" +
    item[3] +
    "</textarea></td><td><textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='" +
    index +
    "_txt'>" +
    item[4] +
    "</textarea></td></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl);

$("body").append("<input type='button' id='btn_1' value='button'>");
$("#btn_1").click(htmltable2json)

function htmltable2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var myRows = [];
  var headersText = [];
  var $headers = $("#table1 th");

  var $rows = $("#table1 tr").each(function(index) {
    $cells = $(this).find("td");
    myRows[index - 1] = {};

    $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
      // Set the header text
      if (headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
        headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
      }
      myRows[index - 1][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).children().first().val() ? $(this).children().first().val() : $(this).text();
    });
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(myRows));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1"></table>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this solved my problem ;D - but could you tell me, why? I mean, I'd understand, if my version wouldn't get me any value, but why does it give me the old value?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more precise to get the value of first `input` or `textarea` instead of first child node? Just a minor change to markup (e.g. adding a wrapping `div`) would make your solution fail.

Comment: @jelhan yes of course, in my opinion all his code could be better anyway

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to get the input value rather than children text or value as follow:

```js
var $tbl = $("#table1");
var index = 1
var item = ["id", "1", "2", "text1", "text2"]
$(
    "<tr><th>Number</th><th>Number 2</th><th>Text</th><th>Text 2</th></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl)
$("<tr><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_from' value='" +
    item[1] +
    "'/></td><td><input type='number' id='" +
    index +
    "_to' value='" +
    item[2] +
    "' /></td><td><textarea rows='1' cols='40' id='" +
    index +
    "_sub'>" +
    item[3] +
    "</textarea></td><td><textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='" +
    index +
    "_txt'>" +
    item[4] +
    "</textarea></td></tr>")
  .appendTo($tbl);

$("body").append("<input type='button' id='btn_1' value='button'>");
$("#btn_1").click(htmltable2json)

function htmltable2json() {
  var json = '{';
  var myRows = [];
  var headersText = [];
  var $headers = $("#table1 th");

  var $rows = $("#table1 tr").each(function(index) {
    $cells = $(this).find("td");
    myRows[index - 1] = {};

    $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
      // Set the header text
      if (headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
        headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
      }
      myRows[index - 1][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(':input', $(this)).val() ? $(':input', $(this)).val() : $(this).text();
    });
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(myRows));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1"></table>
```